# Setup media keys on a keyboard without media shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I recently changed from a macbook to a macpro desktop. My keyboard has no media keys but on the mackbook I was able to use the standard media functions keys when I wanted to skip songs etc. I no longer have that option so is there anyway to map a keyboard shortcut to media controls? FYI My media player is Google play music in Chrome and media keys used to work fine with this. My keyboard is an Apple Extended Keyboard 2 which obviously pre-dates media shortcuts!

Comment: AEKII... Are you sure? That was an ADB keyboard, pre-dating USB. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Extended_Keyboard - full list here... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Keyboard

Comment: Yeah, I have an adapter to USB...I'm a keyboard nerd, got to have mechanical key switches!